# Which color values can be used for GradientDrawable

Tags: java, android, background

In my application i am trying to draw a gradientBackground from code.
My goal is to make this background `dynamic`.

Now is my question this function below is the function i am talking about, and has a parameter `int[] colors`

```
GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation, int[] colors);
```

Which values can i put in int[] colors?
I know the following value works.

- 0xAARRGGBB

But my problem is, i recalculate hash values in my program but they end as a String, but it has to end as an Integer.

And it isn't possible to convert a hash value like: String 0x34F323 to Int 0x34F323.
When i recalculated the hash value and get:

`String: #125BD7`

And i use Integer.Decode("#125BD7");
The output will be a value of seven numbers.
But this doesn't work in the method of GradientDrawable at the int[] parameter.
Because all i get is a black background.

Can someone help me with this? Which values can i use in the GradientDrawable method?

Comment: did you really get G in that String value ??

Comment: No, i made up that value, i edit my post. the real value was: `#125BD7`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Color.parseColor("#45F434");`. Which returns integer. But there should be no `G` in you color code. Only Hex values are acceptable (`0-F`).

Take a look at the [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class reference. Color can be negetive. Take a look at the constants.

Comment: Yes you are true, the value i gave in the post above i made up. But when i am using Color.parseColor, i get indeed a color int. I put this string in the pastColor method: `#125BD7` and the output according the debugger is: -15574057, and i think this isn't a correct value? why is it negative?

Comment: It's still an integer. Edited my answer

Comment: So you are saying -15574057 should work? Negative integers are possible to set as background? Because it doesn't work for this one. I recalculated two hash values, i get two negative 8 digits back. And the application crashes.

Comment: Post your logcat & code segment of calculation. Also make sure only hex characters are present in your calculated value.

Comment: @DanielMartinus cant you directly pass the String value.no need to do this Integer.Decode("#125BD7");

Comment: @AndroidKiller no that isnt possible, becuase the method needs integers, and when you pass a string it will crash.

Comment: @DanielMartinus can't you do Integer.parseInt(string);

Comment: The question is, how do you recalculate your color code? Can you post your recalculating method?